# Run shell script in python with specific parameters

Tags: python, json, shell, terminal, subprocess

I wish to run a script, lets call it *api.sh*. The script takes various arguments,

- -t token
- -r rules.json
- -s data.json

and it is going to create a new json file, e.g. *data_2.json*.

When I run this in terminal I use the following command:

```
./api.sh -t token -r rules.json -s data.json > data_2.json
```

However, I wish to run this command line in Python. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it supports python but you can use `getopts`.

Look [here](https://sookocheff.com/post/bash/parsing-bash-script-arguments-with-shopts/)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the attached link. :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this `test.py` work:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen

path_to_output_file = 'data_2.json'

myoutput = open(path_to_output_file,'w+')

p = Popen(["./api.sh", "-t" , "token", "-r", "rules.json", "-s", "data.json"], stdout=myoutput, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

output, errors = p.communicate()
```

You can refer to [this](https://queirozf.com/entries/python-3-subprocess-examples#popen-example-redirect-output-to-file) for details.